# Openlayers3 markers are not showing up on os map

Tags: javascript, jquery, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

While ago I had help over so about setting up a project where I need to mark random building in NYC and display some info about the building, long story short, I have displayed a openstreetmap using openlayers3, view is fix to Astoria(Queens, NYC).
Now popup is working but markers are not displaying.

I have tried to experiment and change geometry from this

`geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.927870, 40.763633]))`

to this `ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([-73.920935,40.780229], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857')),`

and use `transform` instead `fromLonLat`, but that didn't displayed them, next thing was `src` in `styleIcon`, I have download the standard openlayers3 marker and tried to add it from the image folder like `src: 'img/icon.png'`, but that didn't work to.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on, why are mine markers not displaying properly on the map?

This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/copser/0zpm9mws/2/) for this project, you will see the popup working but no markers.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/copser/0zpm9mws/5/) is updated and it is working now, markers are displaying properly.

```
/* Create the map */

// Elements that make up the popup
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

// Add a click handler to hide the popup.
// @return {boolean}.
closer.onclick = function() {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

// Create an overlay to anchor the popup
// to the map
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});

// setting up coordinates for map to display
var city = ol.proj.transform([-73.920935,40.780229], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'); 

// setting up openlayer3 view
var view = new ol.View({
    center: city,
    zoom: 15
});

// Create the map
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM({
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
      })
    })
  ],
  overlays: [overlay],
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});

// Setup markers
var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.927870, 40.763633])),
        name: 'Crescent St',
        description: 'Apartment'
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.917356, 40.763958])),
        name: 'Long Island City',
        desctiption: 'Apartment'
      })
    ]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixel',
      opacity: 0.75,
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/data/icon.png',
    })
  })
});
map.addLayer(markers);

// Setting up click handler for the map
// to render the popup
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  var name = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature.get('name');
  })
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  content.innerHTML = name;
  overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
});
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
  map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel) ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the https from your src style.

Instead of `src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/data/icon.png',` 
put`src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/data/icon.png',`

You also need to zoom out a bit to see your marks

Comment: Thank you @pavlos, I have tried on JSFiddle and it is working, thank you, it is funny, rely, http over https, hehe

Comment: I know sometimes, jsfiddle doesnt work properly over https. It all depends on the server policy. At least, for testing purposes I use http. glad to help amigo.